# Extracting a substring with a JavaScript regular expression;

Tags: javascript, regex

Consider this code:

```
var myregexp = "\\*(.+)"; // set from another subsystem, that's why I'm not using a literal regexp
var input = "Paypal *Steam Games";
var output = input.match(new RegExp(myregexp, 'gi'), "$1");
```

The output is `["*Steam Games"]`, but I would like it to be just `["Steam Games"]`.

What is wrong?

PS A great resource I found today: http://regex101.com/#javascript

Comment: Is the regular expression only intended to match "Steam Games", or is it intended to match other strings as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var str = "Paypal *Steam Games";

var reg = /\w+\s?\*(\w+\s?\w+)/; // or your exp will work too `/\*(.+)/;`

console.log(reg.exec(str)[1]); // result Steam Games
```

<kbd>[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3WNmv/)</kbd>

You'll get `Steam Games` from your string with help of `/\w+\s?\*(\w+\s?\w+)/` exp

In JavaScript there are three main RegExp functions:

> [exec](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec)  **A RegExp method that executes a search for a match in a
>   string. It returns an array of information.**
>
> [match](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)  **A String method that executes a search for a match in a
>   string. It returns an array of information or null on a mismatch.**
>
> [test](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test)  **A RegExp method that tests for a match in a string. It
>   returns true or false.**

Comment: please explain your answers

Comment: I did explain. No matter how trivial, even if YOU think it's redundant, code dump answers are bad answers in my opinion.

Comment: @RUJordan Also provided JSFiddle example, what else do you want ?

Comment: Code is not an explanation. Words are explanations. Just because it makes sense to you doesn't mean the rest of the world will get it, and those few words can help future googlers. Also, saying "no offense" before something just insinuates offense. You're kind of lucky people didn't downvote you for that alone.

Comment: I haven't ever down voted because of explanation, if someone claims and writes code ( and is a bit on programming world ), will understand everything from my posts. When it is necessary I am explaining. If OP can't understand, I am doing my best to advice him and show the way

Comment: Well when you deem it not necessary to explain your answers, I'll be there with my mouse on the down arrow :D

Comment: @RUJordan okay, just don't forget to comment too

Answer (score 2):

[`match` doesn’t accept a second argument.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)

Since you have the global flag set (and I assume it’s intentional), you’ll need [`exec`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec) to find all of the first groups:

```
var m;

while ((m = re.exec(input)) {
    alert(m[1]); // Get group 1
}
```